# what's the difference of double in mysql and java?

Tags: java, mysql

Have a table,

```
CREATE TABLE `double_test` (
  `price` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

and there are two records:

```
select * from double_test;
+---------+
| price   |
+---------+
| 1100.00 |
| 1396.32 |
+---------+
```

and sum them:

```
select sum(price) from double_test;
+------------+
| sum(price) |
+------------+
|    2496.32 |
+------------+
```

And sum the two double in Java ,

```
System.out.println(1100.00 + 1396.32); //2496.3199999999997
System.out.println((1100.00 + 1396.32) == 2496.32); //false
```

So both are double why in mysql could get correct result?
and what's the difference of double type in mysql and java?

In java if use BigDecimal could get correct result, e.g.

```
     System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(1100.00).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1396.32)).equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(2496.32)));//true
```

Is actually double in mysql equal to BigDecimal in Java?

Comment: Have a look at the explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/2002257 - it will give you some understanding into how doubles work in Java. As for mysql - I would guess it doesn't implement them the same.

Comment: Thanks! but I want to know the difference of double type between mysql and java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: [MySQL Floating-point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the difference of double type in mysql and java?

There is no difference between MySQL `DOUBLE` and Java `Double`.

There is however a difference when using MySQL's [`DOUBLE(m,n)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm140681555549776), since that constrains the value (see below).

> Is actually double in mysql equal to BigDecimal in Java?

No, the MySQL data type [`DECIMAL(m,n)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm140681555606288) is closer in functionality to Java's `BigDecimal`, except that MySQL constrains the value (see below).

**Value Constraints**

Java's `double` stores the full precision supported by a IEEE 64-bit double, and `BigDecimal` is entirely unconstrained.

In contrast, MySQL's `DOUBLE(m,n)` and `DECIMAL(m,n)` constrains the value to `m` total digits, with `n` digits after the decimal point.

As described for `DOUBLE(m,n)`:

> MySQL performs **rounding when storing** values, so if you insert `999.00009` into a `FLOAT(7,4)` column, the approximate result is `999.0001`.

The decimal constraint `n` is also used to format the value when displayed.

As for the calculation of `1100.00 + 1396.32`, [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html) says:

> the precision of the result is the precision of the operand with the maximum precision.

This would mean that the result of the addition is rounded to 2 decimals, which makes a difference when using the approximate numeric data type `DOUBLE`. Java doesn't round the result, so may calculate a result that is slightly different out at the last bit.

Comment: So if in your business only support two digits after decimal point, like 1.23. So in mysql double(m,2) is (safe) enough, no need have to use decimal(m,2).  Am I right?

Comment: @zhuguowei In my opinion, `decimal(m,2)` is better.

Comment: In mysql's `Double(m,n)`, what is the maximum value `m` and `n` can take?

Comment: can I use java BigDecimal with MySQL double, is it compatible?

Answer (score 0):

> and what's the difference of double type in mysql and java?

Shortly: Java has no clue about `(11,2)` part in your MySQL's declaration `double(11,2)`.

The difference is that java's `double` is a general purpose type, that may store an arbitrary value between `4.9e-324` and `1.7e308`, while MySQL creates a different `double` type for every declaration that includes (*digits in total*, *digits after the decimal point*) part.